# Does it matter if I bake a Normal map from a model withouth Color?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

Does it matter if I decide to bake a Normal map from a High Poly mesh to a low poly mesh first and then Create Textures on the low poly one?

Because as of now, I have not created Textures, But I have sculpted detail on the High Poly. Can I just do it withouth textures? It's fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not going to add bump, displacement or normal textures onto the high poly model, then it does not make a difference wether you bake it before or after adding textures.

All sculpted detail will properly be baked regardless of (color) textures.

Comment: No. The High Poly is just there to create the normals, then I don't need it anymore.